# Unable to create folder in Android 11 React Native using React Native FS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-11, react-native-fs, react-native-fetch-blob

```
downloadFile = async (url) => {
   try {
     const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
       {
         title: 'Storage Permission',
         message: 'App needs access to memory to download the file ',
       },
     );
     if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
       console.log("Permission Granted")
       let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.MainBundleDir;
       const execute = await RNFS.mkdir(`${dirs}/Jharkhand Update Database`)
       console.log(execute)
       console.log(dirs);
     } else {
      ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
      'You need to give storage permission to download the file',
      ToastAndroid.SHORT,
      ToastAndroid.BOTTOM,
      );
    }
  } catch (err) {
  console.log('Random ', err);
 }
};
```

Unable to create a folder in android 11. Tried using DocumentDir & SDCardApplicationDir in place of MainBundleDir as well but of no use. It is important to create a folder as we are storing a list of messages which are being sent by the admin so that the app remains accessible even if the mobile data is switched off.

Answer (score 1):

Android 11+ needs the permission `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` alongside with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for any file management to work as itended.

Don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />` and `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` on your `manifest.xml` file

Read more about it [here](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/998) and [here](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/950)

Comment: Already did that but still I am unable to create folder.

Comment: `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` will resolve the issue. But our app won't be approved in the Play Store unless we have a strong reason to use it.